# Forms authentication - keeping user logged in after redirect to Paypal

Tags: model-view-controller, paypal, forms-authentication, umbraco

I have a shopping cart in my Umbraco site - when the user clicks pay they are redirected to Paypal to pay for the contents of the cart.  Once complete, Paypal redirects back to my site courtesy of a return url I specify in m post data.

The return url is a page that contains a list of purchased subscriptions for that user and they need to be logged in to view it.  Since they have to be logged in to click the button that takes them to Paypal I would have expected them to be still logged in when Paypal redirects back to my site but they never are.

I've tried increasing the timeout in the web.config forms element but this has no effect.  It's weird, I can shut the browser down & reaccess my site and still be logged in - it's just this post back from Paypal that seems to screw it up.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you sending back to same scheme (http vs https)?  same domain? subdomain? Clearing cookies at any point? Having a little more detail on the exact steps will be necessary to help here.

Comment: The Paypal url is https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr & the specified return url is http://mydomain.org.uk/publications/subscription-add

When I login to my site I see the auth cookie is generated for www.mydomain.org.uk (AFAIK I have no control over this).  The obvious thing to try is change the return url to have a www prefix.

Comment: I meant to add that the Paypal url is https

Answer (score 0):

After a little more digging as suggested by pc-pdx the problem was that my auth cookie was getting generated for www.mydomain.org.uk but the Paypaf return url was specified as http://mydomain.org.uk.

I changed the return url to http://www.mydomain.org.uk & it fixed it.